# Usage: Escape HTML problem

Tags: html, escaping

I ran into an interesting problem.

In our webpage a user can write their own description. We escape all text to make it easy to write (`<3` shows up properly and isnt the start of a tag). This also avoids any problems with trying to inject their javascript code or hide something or do anything with html.

A side effect is when a user writes

```
Hi

My name is
```

shows up as

```
Hi My name is
```

Initially we (really i) wrote `var desc = (SafeHtml)obj.desc.HtmlEscape.replace("\n", "\n<br>")` however this doesnt replace anything because what really happens is \n is replaced as `#&10;` since all characters < 0x20 (<--i think) needs an escape to be represented in html.

So my question is, am i doing things right? I changed the replace to `("&#10;", "\n<br/>");`. Is this the right way? Escape everything and replace characters you deem 'legal'? ATM i cant think of any other characters to escape.

Comment: Whats with the no Best Practice tags?

Comment: [this post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/) on the Stack Overflow blog explains it.

Answer (score 0):

That's how I'd do it - escape everything, and then replace safe escaped sequences. That said, I don't think you need to replace all characters < 0x20 - I'd leave 0x10 (newline) and 0x13 (carriage return) alone in the escaping step, and then replace them by `<br />`. Doesn't make much difference though.